# Adding and accepting own answer that only says "I did what X said"

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, accepted-answer, reporting

I noticed some questions like "how do I do something?" that several people have answered. Say the answers are "do A", "do B", "do C", ... At the end there is an accepted answer from the person who asked the question that basically says for example "I went with B".

Is that OK according to Stack Exchange's rules / etiquette? If not, what can one do in such case? Report? Flag the answer somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the *only* purpose of the answer is to agree with an existing answer and does not add any additional details or explanation, flag it as "not an answer". It's a comment.

This is what upvotes are for and adding them as an answer is outside the standard usage of the site.

However, if the answer is:

> I did what B did but I made a couple of changes (d, e, f and g) because B by itself didn't work for me entirely.

**This** is still valuable content because it adds detail with explanation (hopefully) why B didn't work for them.

Unfortunately, with accepted answers, they can't be deleted so your recourse is to leave a comment letting them know that their "answer" isn't an answer and that they should accept the answer they used rather than writing their own and/or downvote.

Fortunately, self-answers that are accepted don't get the accepted bump to the top.  This is crummy for whoever wrote the actual answer but comments and downvotes will hopefully help the op see the error. It's completely possible that other sites they've used follow this practice and they need help learning how Stack Exchange works. Help teach them.